# Error in c socket programing : after accept(), program goes to shut down.

Tags: c, sockets, proxy, server

I made a simple proxy server code with C. It works only when it tried to connect to [www.yahoo.com/news.html](http://www.yahoo.com/news.html)

But other site doesn't.(e.g. google or cnn and so on)

When the program goes to 'accept()' first, it's OK.

All variable has their own values.

But after second 'accept()' caused by 'while()', the program shut down.

until then, variables (sockfd2, newsockfd) still have their own value.

It is weird, because I closed them before to go to while().

I really don't know why my program shutdown, and why it tell me "address already in use" sometimes.

Is there something I missed? Plz tell me.

Here is the code.

```
/* 
   A simple server in the internet domain using TCP
   Usage:./server port (E.g. ./server 10000 )
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>   // definitions of a number of data types used in socket.h and netinet/in.h
#include <sys/socket.h>  // definitions of structures needed for sockets, e.g. sockaddr
#include <netinet/in.h>  // constants and structures needed for internet domain addresses, e.g. sockaddr_in
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <netdb.h>      // define structures like hostent

void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

char *replaceAll(char *s, const char *olds, const char *news) {
  char *result, *sr;
  size_t i, count = 0;
  size_t oldlen = strlen(olds); if (oldlen < 1) return s;
  size_t newlen = strlen(news);


  if (newlen != oldlen) {
    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0';) {
      if (memcmp(&s[i], olds, oldlen) == 0) count++, i += oldlen;
      else i++;
    }
  } else i = strlen(s);


  result = (char *) malloc(i + 1 + count * (newlen - oldlen));
  if (result == NULL) return NULL;


  sr = result;
  while (*s) {
    if (memcmp(s, olds, oldlen) == 0) {
      memcpy(sr, news, newlen);
      sr += newlen;
      s  += oldlen;
    } else *sr++ = *s++;
  }
  *sr = '\0';

  return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, newsockfd; //descriptors rturn from socket and accept system calls
    int sockfd2, newsockfd2; //Socket descriptor
    int portno; // port number
    int portno2, n2;

    socklen_t clilen;

    char buffer[1024];
    char resMsg[2048];
    char bufferForAddr[1024]; 
    char ip[100];

     /*sockaddr_in: Structure Containing an Internet Address*/
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr2;
    struct hostent *server2; //contains tons of information, including the server's IP address
    struct in_addr **addr_list;

    int n;
    if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }

     /*Create a new socket
       AF_INET: Address Domain is Internet 
       SOCK_STREAM: Socket Type is STREAM Socket */
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");

    /*browser's port no is 80*/
    portno2 = 80;
    sockfd2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); //create a new socket
    if (sockfd2 < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");

     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     portno = atoi(argv[1]); //atoi converts from String to Integer
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; //for the server the IP address is always the address that the server is running on
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno); //convert from host to network byte order   

     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) //Bind the socket to the server address
              error("ERROR on binding");

     listen(sockfd,5); // Listen for socket connections. Backlog queue (connections to wait) is 5

     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
     /*accept function: 
       1) Block until a new connection is established
       2) the new socket descriptor will be used for subsequent communication with the newly connected client.
     */
    while(1){

        printf("==========================main========================\n");
         newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
         if (newsockfd < 0) 
              error("ERROR on accept");

         bzero(buffer,1024);

         n = read(newsockfd,buffer,1023); //Read is a block function. It will read at most 255 bytes
         if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
            printf("Here is the message1: %s\n",buffer);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            /*
            get an info about destination site from browser(client)
            */
        printf("Here is the message2: %s\n",buffer);
        char *reqMSG;
        char *address;

        reqMSG = replaceAll(buffer, "HTTP/1.1", "HTTP/1.0");
        reqMSG = replaceAll(reqMSG, "keep-alive", "close");
        //strcat(reqMSG, "\r\nProxy-Connection: keep-alive\r\n");
        strcat(reqMSG,"\r\n");
        //printf("MSG : %s",reqMSG);

        strcpy(bufferForAddr,buffer);
        address = strtok(bufferForAddr+11," ");
        address = strtok(address,"/");
        printf("address : %s\n",address);
        printf("MSG : %s\n",reqMSG);
        /*
        Q2. make a algorithm for filtering about cached site.
        */       
        /*
        if the site is not cached, send the Msg to it's ip address!
        in this section, I need to use functions each called connect, write and read.
        */



        server2 = gethostbyname(address); //takes a string like "www.yahoo.com", and returns a struct hostent which contains information, as IP address, address type, the length of the addresses...
        //get an ip address from hostname
        /*
        addr_list = (struct in_addr **) server2->h_addr_list;
        int i;
        for(i = 0; addr_list[i] != NULL; i++) 
        {
            strcpy(ip , inet_ntoa(*addr_list[i]) );
        }  
*/
        if (server2 == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        bzero((char *) &serv_addr2, sizeof(serv_addr2));
        serv_addr2.sin_family = AF_INET; //initialize server's address
        bcopy((char *)server2->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr2.sin_addr.s_addr, server2->h_length);
        serv_addr2.sin_port = htons(portno2);


        if (connect(sockfd2,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr2,sizeof(serv_addr2)) < 0){ //establish a connection to the server
            error("ERROR connecting");
        }
                        //send a REQ MSG from above step!

        //do{
        n2 = write(sockfd2,reqMSG,strlen(reqMSG)); //write to the socket
        if (n2 < 0) {
             error("ERROR writing to socket");
             //break;
         }
        printf("What's wrong : %s\n",reqMSG);
        printf("%s\n",resMsg);
        bzero(resMsg,2047);

       while (n2 = read(sockfd2,resMsg,2047)>0){ //read from the socket
        printf("=================================sub=============================\n");
        if (n2 < 0){ 
             error("ERROR reading from socket");
            //break;
        }
        printf("resMsg : %s\n",resMsg);
        //printf("\nI'm in the loop!\n");
       //}while(1);
            /*
            if I get response Msg to my destination site, I will return it to my source site.
            and wait for closing Msg to browser(client).
            */


         write(newsockfd,resMsg,n2); //NOTE: write function returns the number of bytes actually sent out Ñ> this might be less than the number you told it to send
         if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
         bzero(resMsg,2047);
        }

        close(sockfd2);

         /*
            make a log file and save this site!
         */
        //printf("\nip : %s \n",ip);
        close(newsockfd);
     }
     close(sockfd);



     return 0; 
}
```

Comment: this line: if (n2 < 0){  will never be true because the while code block, in which it exists will exit if n2 <= 0

Answer (score 0):

befor bind try to

```
int tr=1;
if(setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &tr, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
    perror("setsockopt");
 }
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Still the program is stucked. But I want to know what this code means.